# Python Nornir AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to use Nornir with its netmiko plugin to do a simple task on an aruba switch.

The following error keeps appear:

```
  File "/home/aruba/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nornir_utils/plugins/inventory/yaml_inventory.py", line 26, in _get_connection_options
    hostname=c.get("hostname"),
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Could you please help me to resolve this?

```
from nornir import InitNornir

from nornir_netmiko.tasks import netmiko_send_command

from nornir_utils.plugins.functions import print_result

NORNIR_CONFIG_FILE = "/home/aruba/config.yaml"

nr = InitNornir(config_file=NORNIR_CONFIG_FILE)

nr = nr.filter(role="access")

def show_ip(task):
    task.run(task=netmiko_send_command, command_string="show ip")

result = nr.run(task=show_ip)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print_result(result)
```

here are my config files:

```
config.yaml:

inventory: 
  plugin: YAMLInventory
  options:
    host_file: "/home/aruba/inventory/hosts.yaml"
    group_file: "/home/aruba/inventory/groups.yaml"
    defaults_file: "/home/aruba/inventory/defaults.yaml"  

runner:
  plugin: threaded
  options: 
    num_workers: 10

logging:
  enabled: True
  level: INFO

hosts.yaml:

aruba:
  hostname: 10.10.10.10
  groups:
    - aos

groups.yaml:

aos:
  platform: aruba_os
  data:
      role: access
      site: center
      building: main
  connection_options:
      netmiko:
      extras:
          use_keys: true
          key_file: "/home/aruba/.ssh/known_hosts"
```

Comment: can you show the whole traceback?